# Cross version tomcat session replication is possible?

Tags: tomcat

A tomcat 6 server is running.
I am going to develop another webapp which will be running on tomcat 7 server instance.
It's required for them to share their login sessions to each other.

Is it possible? If so, do you think it's supposed to be reliable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible if you're using a cluster and `session persistence with a database` See the docs for more info... [Session Replication](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html)

Comment: If its a cluster you need to deploy the 'same' app twice, to make the delta manager replicate the session. If its the same app you can use two servers of  version 7. Why do you want to share the session. Maybe you are looking for something like single sign on?

Comment: Yes, Stefan, they are different apps and I want them to share their login sessions like single sign on.